# C# Entity Framework - beginner

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The database relation looks like this at the moment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzvnp.png

I've got a connector table called friendship, which holds 2 values and a key ID. This table describes that X friends Y, but Y might not friend X. So it's some kind of linear stuff.

I would like to model the same in Entity Framework, but I fail all the time because I get this error:

> may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

I made two tables in EF:

```
class Friendship
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int whoid { get; set; }
    public int whomid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("whoid")]
    public virtual Person who { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("whomid")]
    public virtual Person whom { get; set; }
}

class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set;} 
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string hnum { get; set; }
    public string bday { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("who")]
    public virtual List<Friendship> wholist { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("whom")]
    public virtual List<Friendship> whomlist { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930715/entity-framework-code-first-how-to-map-multiple-self-referencing-many-to-many-r

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to write your code as below and add correct relationship.

```
class Friendship
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("who")]
    public int whoid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("whom")]
    public int whomid { get; set; }


    public virtual Person who { get; set; }


    public virtual Person whom { get; set; }
}

class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set;} 
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string hnum { get; set; }
    public string bday { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("who")]
    public virtual List<Friendship> wholist { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("whom")]
    public virtual List<Friendship> whomlist { get; set; }
}
```

Also you need to add below code for relationship between entities in your DB context file.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>()
                    .HasRequired(e => e.who)
                    .WithMany(t => t.wholist)
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.whoid)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>()
                    .HasRequired(e => e.whom)
                    .WithMany(t => t.whomlist)
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.whomid)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);   




}
```

Comment: As soon as I try to save my changes deubugger shows an exception:

"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Friendships_dbo.People_whoid"

Comment: The reason behind this is when you are inserting a record on the child table which the value of the referencing column doesn't exist yet on the on the parent table.

Answer (score 0):

In Entityframework u cannot add more than one foreign key of same Class that whey it getting Error.. remove any of this....

```
[ForeignKey("whoid")]
public virtual Person who { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("whomid")]
public virtual Person whom { get; set; }
```

I think this problem you also get when adding in sqlserver