# Deleting entity in many-to-many results in: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint *

Tags: database, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

My data model looks the following:

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Job> Dependencies { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Job> Dependants { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And in my context I have the following relationship defined:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Dependants)
        .WithMany(x => x.Dependencies);
}
```

Now whenever I try to delete a job I get the following error:

> "{"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   \"FK_dbo.JobJobs_dbo.Jobs_Job_Id\". The conflict occurred in database
>   \"Testing\", table \"dbo.JobJobs\", column 'Job_Id'.\r\nThe statement
>   has been terminated."}"

What's the issue here? I just want the job to be deleted.

I'm using EF6 by the way.

Comment: What code are you using to delete? Are there other tables that are using the Job's `Id`?

Comment: Could be some sort of circular self reference error. You could check the generated SQL to be sure. Here is a similar config: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930715/entity-framework-code-first-how-to-map-multiple-self-referencing-many-to-many-r