# MVC EF 6 Virtual Property Custom select in data model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I think I understand this correctly but I want to make sure. I am using Entity Framework 6 and I have a data model `person.cs` and I want to link people on the table to "partners" (which are also on that table) so I created another model `personPartner.cs` with

```
public int id {get;set;}
public int personID{get;set;}
public int partnerID{get;set;}
public virtual Person Person { get { return _context.People.Find(PartnerId); } }
```

I then put

```
public virtual ICollection<personPartner> PeoplePartners { get; set; }
```

in `person.cs` and I get pretty much the linking and references I want. What I realized, though, is that this relationship is only going to find the partners if you are looking at the original person (whose id is in the `personID` field of `personPartner.cs`) and NOT if you are looking at the partner (whose id is in the `partnerID` field of `personPartner.cs`). So then I was thinking, in order to link them both ways, I could change `person.cs` to have:

```
public virtual ICollection<personPartner> PeoplePartners
  { 
    get
      {
        return _context.personPartners.Where(x=> x.personID == Id || x.partnerID ==  ID).Select(x);} }
```

Is that correct? Is that the best way to do it so that I can link a person to other persons on the same table and then have them be pulled regardless of which one you are looking at, the original person or the partner?

I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

So what I am looking for, more specifically, is the following:

Right now, when I call a record from `person.cs`, I get a single `person` entry and all the `personPartner` entries where `personPartner.PersonId == personId` from the `ICollection<personPartner>` property, which EF did for me automatically. What I want, however, is a way to call a single `person.cs` record and get all `personPartner` records where `personPartner.PersonId == personId || person.Partner.PartnerId == person.Id` from that same `ICollection<personPartner>` property.

Thank you

Comment: Having `_context.People` inside an entity is certainly not a good idea. That's not how navigation properties work. Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26931904/861716) to get some inspiration.

Comment: That should basically work, as far as the concept. I think you probably want to change it to use `PeoplePartners.Where(...)` instead of `People.Where(...)`?  It would help if, in your question, you could modify it and provide a sample of what your underlying table structure and sample data looks like. Maybe include what you would be looking for as a subset of data that you are attempting to collect using your code.

Comment: @GertArnold thank you for the link. I can tell that post is related but it didn't quite explain it enough for me. Do I have to manually create those `Person_Sisters` and `Person_Brothers` tables? How do I link them on certain properties and then call that data?
@gmiley I updated the question to include a specific example of what I am getting and what I want